# Meaning of “this food has a bite to it”

Tags: meaning, word-usage, american-english, food

If I say “I prefer my steak/burger to have a bite to it”, I’m referring to it having enough thickness or density. Is this a proper usage of the word “bite”? My wife says she’s always heard the word used this way too. I looked at several websites for definitions/uses of the word, and found nothing like the usage I’m thinking of.

Comment: ***bite*** in such contexts could mean EITHER "piquant" (as in ***contains chilli***) OR "having a texture that you can get your teeth into" ("coarse" sausage with "chewy" bits, as opposed to a sausage made with smooth "mechanically-recovered meat" that's been pulverised to a slushy paste before being dried a bit and extruded into sausage skins).

Comment: ...but I don't think many people would use "bite" in relation to a ***steak*** with the "texture" sense, even though I've heard lots of people say things like *Fillet steak is okay, but I'd rather have a  rump steak that I can really get my teeth into* (rump steak usually being much "tougher" than fillet steak, as well as possibly "tastier").

Comment: 'This storecupboard relish has all the flavours of a classic cooked chutney but with more bite.' [[BBC Good Food](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/collection/apple-chutney-recipes)] I'd assume more piquancy.

Comment: Something that has bite to it is not generally associated with food! So, it could be used as a joke. A speech, presentation, article, can have bite to it. Comments can have bite to them.

Comment: https://youtu.be/pJaVvE1s_yw

Comment: @Lambie "Bite" is definitely associated with food for me, as Fumble Fingers says it most commonly means piquancy or spiciness. I don't associate it with texture though.

Comment: @BoldBen Ok, a sauce or salad dressing can have bite. A spice can have bite. But I would not say: This food has bite. This lemon gives this chicken bite. Yes. But not like the OP said: I prefer my steak to have bite.

Answer (score 2):

[***al dente***](https://www.thespruceeats.com/what-is-al-dente-995554)

...would seem to cover that concept, but I have usually heard it  in reference to *pasta*.

In my family, *al dente* means it is "toothy", or semi-resistant to the bite.

[**mouth feel**](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/blog/2360/what-is-mouthfeel.html)

can include texture, etc

As the butcher's boy, it sounds like tough v soft. As the physical science teacher, it sounds like a conflation of metrics.

Comment: "Al dente" really refers to the effect of restricted cooking leaving the item slightly resistant to the pressure of the teeth, in some people's opinion "a bit raw". It is often applied to vegetables and to pasta but not, in my experience, to meat. The equivalent for steak is "rare" but then steak gets tougher the more it's cooked whereas vegetables and pasta get softer.

Comment: @BoldBen I actually agree completely...hence the caveat. I think 'mouth feel', while broad, covers it better.